# Variadic template acting weird

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++11, intel, variadic-templates

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a compiler bug. I'm using Intel C++ Composer XE 2011 for Windows with SP1 (or update 6, which is currently the latest). See the commented lines in the code.

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

template <typename ...T>
struct first_va_arg {};

template <typename T0, typename ...T_>
struct first_va_arg<T0, T_...> {
    typedef T0    type;
};

template <typename ...T>
inline first_va_arg<T...>::type getFirstArgTypeDefaultValue( const T& ...values )
{
//Next line causes error: nontype "first_va_arg<T...>::type [with T=<T...>]" is not a type name
    typedef first_va_arg<T...>::type    FirstArgT;
    return FirstArgT();
//It works correctly if you comment out the above two lines and uncomment the single line below
    //return first_va_arg<T...>::type();
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << getFirstArgTypeDefaultValue(5.67, 32) << std::endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have *dependent name*, you need to say `typename`:

```
template <typename ...T> inline typename first_va_arg<T...>::type getFirstArgTypeDefaultValue( const T& ...values )
//                              ^^^^^^^^
{
  typedef typename first_va_arg<T...>::type FirstArgT;
  //..
}
```

Note that you are missing the base case for *no* parameters. I would probably do away with the partial specialization and just declare the primary template as:

```
template <typename T, typename...> struct first_va_arg  { typedef T type; };
```

Then, when you say `first_va_arg<>::type`, you don't get a "non-existing name" error, but a potentially more meaningful "template parameter mismatch". Up to you. Alternatively you could only *declare* the primary template but leave it undefined.

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten all about typename because Intel compiler has quite relaxed requirements for those. But this time it was needed for the typedef. But you don't need to add typename for the function return type (on this compiler at least).

Comment: Well, if we're talking about C++ the language, then you do have to add it. If we're talking about your compiler and its extensions and specifics, then I'm afraid I don't know, as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I thought the relaxed rules about typename came along with c++11, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You could also declare the case for no parameters, and include a `static_assert(false)`.